# How to end logic flow with React Infinite Scroll after onLoadMore callback

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

I have been struggling with [React Inifinity Scroll](https://cassetterocks.github.io/react-infinite-scroller/), I am sure the answer is obvious just have not found the answer in their bare minimal documentation.

In the logic flow below I don't understand how to do the 3rd step:

1. Infinite Scroll is triggered the onLoadMore event
2. The data is fetched and the list (passed to Inifinity Scroll) is updated
3. Send signal to Infinite Scroll the end of the flow and it now waits for next onLoadMore event

Currently What is happening is that the onLoadMore event is triggered, the data is fetched but the loader is blocked (waiting the the 3rd step), onLoadMore events are no longer triggered because is not completed. 
So Infinite Scroll is only triggering the first onLoadMore event, then stuck.

The code is as follows:

```
export default class List extends React.Component {

    handleOnLoadMore () {
        // fetch and update data
        ...
    }

    render() {
        // construct list of items
        const innerItemlist = ...

        return (
            <InfiniteScroll
                pageStart={0}
                loadMore={this.handleOnLoadMore.bind(this)}
                hasMore={true}
                loader={<LoaderInline/>}>
                {innerItemList}
            </InfiniteScroll>
        )
    }
}
```

Does the handleOnLoadMore function take a callback which can be called signalling the end of the flow?
Or maybe some other parameter can be passed to InfiniteScroll that I need to pass?

Comment: What is your problem anyway? Your fetch data cannot be rendered?

Comment: @FiriceNguyen The problem is that the onLoadMore event is only being fired onces, after the data is updated it seems to keep waiting for the process to finish. So the next time you scroll down the onLoadMore event is not triggered.

Comment: Does this trick `style={{overflowY: 'auto', height: '100vh'}}`  on your componenet solve the problem ?